# Alt+F4 with ControlSend in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

```
SetKeyDelay , 1000, 50    

$Pause::
ControlSend, , !{F11}, A,
ControlSend, , {F5}, A,
ControlSend, , {Enter}, A,
ControlSend, , {Enter}, A,
ControlSend, , !{F4}, A

Return
```

hi guys, I tried this but it worked prior to the Alt F4, couldn't figure out why... thanks in advance

Comment: Try `PostMessage, WM_QUIT:=0x12, 0, 0, , A` instead of sending Alt-F4.

Comment: thanks but didn't work either =(

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Is there an error message when you try to run your code? Do the other send commands work as expected? Does the code work if you try ControlSend on it's own?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, Alt+F4 does not work unless it's the active window.

As an alternative, have you considered [`WinClose`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm)?

Assuming `A` is your WinTitle:

```
WinClose, A
```